# "GetProfiles" does not work with my ONVIF camera

Tags: python-3.x, onvif, python-onvif

My task is to control the Cisco ptz camera. However, I can’t even get a token. I successfully connect to the camera, but I get an error when I execute GetProfiles (). Through ONVIF Device Manager, everything works fine and I can see tokens and other information about my camera

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from onvif import ONVIFCamera
>>> mycam = ONVIFCamera("***.***.***.***", 15080, "admin", "********")
>>> media = mycam.create_media_service()
>>> poflist = media.GetProfiles()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f125b8bf7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.203', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /onvif/device_service (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f125b8bf7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 153, in wrapped
    return call(params, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 140, in call
    ret = func(**params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 122, in send
    response = client.transport.post_xml(options["address"], envelope, http_headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 95, in post_xml
    return self.post(address, message, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 62, in post
    address, data=message, headers=headers, timeout=self.operation_timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 567, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.203', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /onvif/device_service (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f125b8bf7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/onvif/client.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise ONVIFError(err)
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.203', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /onvif/device_service (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f125b8bf7f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are pointing to the correct entry for the `device_service`? In some infrequent cases, it may be that the ONVIF interface runs on a port different from 80, where the webinterface is running.

In this case, usually a camera responds to the Probe messages by listing the XAddr for the device service with a port different form 80.

I suggest you to use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and to sniff the traffic between ONVIF Device Manager and the camera and to check the correct URI used by ONVIF Device Manager to post the requests.